# How to take a value of the input given in a file into an array with specified format

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Input Format is

```
6
4 5 1 9 8 7
```

Where first line gives the length of the array or the number of character

Required Output

```
array{4,5,1,9,8,7}


 <?php

    $fp = fopen("C://wamp//www//phptut////Insertion Sort//stdin.txt", "r");

    $m = (int) fgets($fp);  
    var_dump($m); 
    $arr = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<$m; $i++) {
        fscanf($fp, "%d", $arr[$i]);
    }
    //var_dump($arr);


    foreach($arr as $value) {
      print $value;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: I am not able to track the values using fscanf() ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $fp = fopen("your file loc", "r");
    fscanf($fp, "%d", $m);
    $ar= fgets($fp);
    $arr = explode(" ", $ar);   
  // here this explode and implode is done because here whatever you want to do with your array ..do it 
    $value = implode(" ", $arr);
    print $value;
```